# prop() not changing id value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is the part of my code that is not working exactly as i would. Everything goes perfectly till

```
data.find("#idToSet").prop("name","post"+element.idpost);
```

i don't understand why this part of the code is not executed. I've tried attr() too , but still nothing. I've checked the HTML and the mark-up is correct, but still not getting the value for the name attribute set.

```
let params = {};
  params.action = "checkpost";
  let db = new Connection(params,"/php/connection.php",false);
  db.go().then(function(data){
    if (data.result == "success"){
      (data.posts).forEach(function(element){
        prepareView("post").then(function(data){
          data = $(data);
          data.find("#postitle").text(element.titolo);
          data.find("#postcontent").text(element.contenuto);
          data.find("#postdate").text("Creato da "+element.nickname+" il "+element.postdate);
          data.find("#idToSet").prop("name","post"+element.idpost);
          $("#postree").append(data);
        });

      });
    }
  });
```

UPDATE

Here is the HTML regarding the issue:

```
<div id="idToSet" name="" class="blog-post shadow-sm mypost">
  <h4 id="postitle" class="blog-post-title"></h4>
  <p id="postdate" class="blog-post-meta"> <a id="postautor" href="#"></a></p>

  <p id="postcontent"></p>

</div>
```

Comment: What do you see if you do this right before that line: `console.log(data.find("#idToSet").length);`

Comment: The lenght of the object is 0, but i don't understand why. The post is correctly created and appended to body.

Comment: That's your issue. If the `#idToSet` is the root of the `data` node, try using `filter()` instead. Without seeing the content of `data` we can't really help any further.

Comment: I've added the html content of `data`

Comment: Yep, in that case `#idToSet` is the root node, so you need to use `filter('#isToSet')` for that. I added an answer below with an example for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the HTML of `data` in your question `#idToSet` is the root node, hence `find()` won't work as you're looking *within* the element you're trying to find.

To solve this issue, use `filter()` for that line instead:

```
data.filter("#idToSet").prop("name", "post" + element.idpost);
```

I would also suggest removing the `id` from the `data` element as well, as currently your code is duplicating them in the loop, which will create invalid HTML. To do add this method to the above line:

```
.removeAttr('id');
```